# How to run AWS codeartifact login and keep default registry

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact, .npmrc

I run this commande in a package.json file (`scripts` > `preinstall`) or (`scripts` > `prepare`):

```
aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain --domain-owner <123456789> --profile <me>
```

**full file:** (`<123456789>` and `<me>` is modified for stackoverflow)

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm run co:login",
    "co:login": "aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain --domain-owner <123456789> --profile <me>",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "@my-npm/my-common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**My `.npmrc` file before `aws codeartifact login ..` commande:**

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@my-npm:registry=https://my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/-repo/
```

**My `.npmrc` file is modified:**

```
registry=https://my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/-repo/
@my-npm:registry=https://my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/-repo/
//my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/my-repo/:always-auth=true
//my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/my-repo/:_authToken=eyJ2ZXIiOjEsIml....
```

but I need keep this:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@my-npm:registry=https://my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/-repo/
//my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/my-repo/:always-auth=true
//my-domain-<123456789>.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/npm/my-repo/:_authToken=eyJ2ZXIiOjEsIml....
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add `--namespace @my-npm` at the end of commande line

This parameter added change only the scope `@my-npm:registry=...` in `.npmrc` file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28467371)

Comment: I would like to see that explanation in the answer. We need to provide complete answers with explanations so people can understand instead of dummy copy paste

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz, yes, that answers the question. if you add --namespace `@my-npm` at the end of command line, the default registry is not affected.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I've been using for this matter is instead of using `aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain` to login into aws I use a more granular approach using the following commands:

```
# get endpoint 
endpoint = aws codeartifact get-repository-endpoint --domain my_domain --domain-owner 111122223333 --repository my_repo --format npm

# set a scoped registry
npm config set registry endpoint --scope=@my-package

# get token
token = aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain my_domain --domain-owner 111122223333 --repository my_repo

# set token
npm config set //my_domain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/npm/my_repo/:_authToken=token

# always truth
npm config set //my_domain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/npm/my_repo/:always-auth=true
```

These commands are a deconstruction of `aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository my-repo --domain my-domain` ([more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/npm-auth.html)), with the difference that instead of setting a general `registry` at your `.npmrc` file (used to set configurations for your npm) will set a **scoped registry** ([more info](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry)).
In this way you will be able to have you fetch your packages from the sources you want.
Applying this to the `package.json` you can insert those commands the value of `co:login` or even isolate the commands in a script and call these script as the value.