# How to login to codeartifact for a single project

Tags: npm, aws-codeartifact, yarnpkg-v3

I have the following structure:

```
nodejs_projects_directory
    ├ project_A
    │   └ node_modules/codeartifact_dependencies
    └ project_B
        └ node_modules/npm_dependencies
```

I have to login to codeartifact to install the `project_A` dependencies, but then if I have to work on `project_B`, the `npm install`/`yarn install` goes to `project_A`'s codeartifact repository. I have to either delete the `~/.npmrc` file or login to codeartifact from the CLI every time I want to switch between the projects. Is there a way to scope the codeartifact auth token to a specific directory?

I referred to this question:
[How to run AWS codeartifact login and keep default registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491276/how-to-run-aws-codeartifact-login-and-keep-default-registry)

But it says about namespacing not directory specific login.